# Backbone Collection multiple on() listeners

Tags: collections, backbone.js, listener

I have multiple listeners in my `initialize` for my view, looks like this:

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render);

this.collection.on('add', this.render);

this.collection.on('change', this.render);
```

I'm curious if there's a way to combine all of them since they all fire the `render`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you can try

```
this.collection.on("reset add change", this.render);
```

Look at [this](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on). It works as its displayed there, but not sure about binding it with default collection events.